# How to toggle between two functions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I don't understand what's wrong with my code? I want to toggle between two functions in jQuery upon click. Thanks

```
$(".col-md-3").toggle(
        function()
            $(this).animate({
            left: "-5px",
            top:"-5px"
            }, 100);,
        function()
            $(this).animate({
            left: "5px",
     top:"5px"
     }, 100);
);
```

Comment: You could simply have one class that is added to the div and toggle it on and off and have CSS transitions on that class.so that the animation is provided on the toggle.

Comment: Your function does not contain   `{`  and  `}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be incorrectly formatted e.g. no opening/closing braces etc.

Can you try this code?

```
$(".col-md-3").toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-5px",
            top:  "-5px"
        }, 100);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "5px",
            top:  "5px"
        }, 100);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function bodies need to be in `{` and `}`, it's not optional like it is with one line `if` statements, if that's what you were thinking.

```
$(".col-md-3").toggle(
  function(){
    $(this).animate({ left: "-5px", top:"-5px" }, 100);
  },
  function(){
    $(this).animate({ left: "5px", top:"5px" }, 100);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out :) That's a silly mistake... 
Once I've tried out I realised this is not exactly what I want. I initially want the object to animate once it was 'clicked' and animate back to the original state when 'click' again.

If I start with:

$('.col-md-3').on('click', boxMove);

function boxMove() {

```
$(this).animate({
    left: "-5px",
    top:"-5px"
}, 100);
```

};

It only animates one way. How could I add in the function that if the (this) is already animate it should move left "5px" and top "5px" to return to the original (unanimated) state?

Thank you so much in advance!